# Including a github jquery plugin in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, github, plugins

I am trying to include a plugin from github (https://github.com/rendro/countdown) **the right way** on my wordpress site. After hours of research in the codex and here on stack I still cannot find a way to make it work.

**If I use the default method:**

1) Adding these lines to the `<head>` of my `header.php` file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
```

2) Initializing the plugin with my desired configuration in between `</head>` and `<body>` in my `header.php` file, in this case:

```
<script>

    $(function() {
        var endDate = "November 30, 2015 10:00:00";

            $('.countdown.styled').countdown({
                date: endDate,
                render: function(data) {
                $(this.el).html("<div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.days, 2) + " <span>days</span></div><div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.hours, 2) + " <span>hours</span></div><div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.min, 2) + " <span>minutes</span></div><div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.sec, 2) + " <span>seconds</span></div>");
                }
            });
    });

</script>
```

3) And then calling the plugin in my html file:

```
<?php if(is_front_page() ) { ?>

    <div id="cdtoevent" class="countcont">
    <div class="countdown styled"></div>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

**It works perfectly !**

---

If, however, I try doing it **the right way**

(If I understand well, wordpress ships with jQuery by default, by using the default method I'm making the user download jquery twice which augments my loading time as well, right ?)

Which means enqueuing jquery and then my script in my `functions.php` file like so:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

function add_cdtoevent() {
        wp_enqueue_script('countdown', get_template_directory_uri() . 'countdown.js', array('jquery'), true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_cdtoevent' );
```

And then repeat step 2) and 3) of the default method, it simply **does not** work ! I tried wrapping my jquery code in step 2) just like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

    // $ Works! You can test it with next line if you like
    // console.log($);

});
```

But it still does not work. 
If anybody could help, it would truly be greatly appreciated !

What I currently have in my `header.php`:

```
<?php if(is_front_page() ) { ?>

     <div id="cdtoevent" class="countcont">
     <div class="countdown styled"></div>
     </div>

<?php } ?>
```

What I currently have in my `footer.php`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        var endDate = "November 14, 2015 10:00:00";

            $('.countdown.styled').countdown({
                date: endDate,
                render: function(data) {
                        $(this.el).html("<div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.days, 2) + " <span>days</span></div><div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.hours, 2) + " <span>hours</span></div><div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.min, 2) + " <span>minutes</span></div><div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.sec, 2) + " <span>seconds</span></div>");
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

What I currently have in my `functions.php` :

```
// Loads JavaScript file with functionality specific to LCQC.

wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

function add_cdtoevent() {
        wp_enqueue_script('countdown', get_template_directory_uri() . 'countdown.js', array('jquery'), true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_cdtoevent' );
```

[The jquery plugin](https://github.com/rendro/countdown/blob/master/dest/jquery.countdown.js)  (.js)

Comment: Script in `head` makes the website slow. It;s better to use script just before your closing body tag. This way all the content is loaded. When that is done the javascript is loaded. This way the user Already sees something.

Comment: My script tag is located in between my `</head>` and `<body>` tags and not in `<head>`. Thank you for this little advice though. I will make sure to modify that !

Comment: How is it not working? Any error in console?

Comment: I was getting errors such as "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function" and others. But I finally got it to work, my mistake was mainly where I had placed my function in my function.php file.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to use a function to enqueue your script. However: where do you call this function? You need to call it to enqueue your script. The best way to do this is by attach it to the right action (`wp_enqueue_scripts`): `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_cdtoevent');`.

I wrote a guide about [including scripts in WordPress](http://www.sitepoint.com/including-javascript-in-plugins-or-themes) if you want more information about this function. It's useful to know how it works, as you can then discover that enqueuing jQuery manually is useless: you indicated that it's a dependency, so WordPress will automatically add it if needed.

Comment: I actually read your article this morning !

I tried this :

`add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'your-script', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/your-script.js', // this is the location of your script file
        array('jquery') // this array lists the scripts upon which your script depends
    );
}`

But it did not seem to work.
What you're telling me is that I do not need "wp_enqueue_script('jquery');" since I used "array" ?

Comment: Just edited my post, as this (`add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_cdtoevent' );`) was already added right after my function. I still get this error though : "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function". Je viens juste de voir que tu es français, que le monde est petit :'D.

Comment: Maybe a problem in the order in which scripts are included? If your script tries to use `$` before the inclusion of jQuery, it won't work. To be sure that your scripts are included in the right order, put your script in an external file and enqueue this file the same way you include the others (with the jQuery plugin as a dependency).

(I continue to write in English, so everyone can find the answer if they search :) )

Comment: I actually just found the solution after going through it all step by step and verifying everything. (I continued to write in English afterward for the same reasons, no worries). My main mistake was that I had placed my function and add_action within an existing function. It was still hard to find the right combination for it to work but I did it ! Thank you again for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work !

First, I had misplaced this as it was within another function in my `functions.php` file..

```
// Loads JavaScript file with functionality specific to LCQC.

wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

function add_cdtoevent() {
        wp_enqueue_script('countdown', get_template_directory_uri() . 'countdown.js', array('jquery'), true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_cdtoevent' );
```

Afterward, I made sure my script was declared this way (due to the noConflict() variable wordpress uses) right before my closing body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(function() {
        var endDate = "November 14, 2015 10:00:00";
            $('.countdown.styled').countdown({
                date: endDate,
                render: function(data) {
                        $(this.el).html("<div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.days, 2) + " <span>days</span></div><div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.hours, 2) + " <span>hours</span></div><div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.min, 2) + " <span>minutes</span></div><div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.sec, 2) + " <span>seconds</span></div>");
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

And finally, I modified the following lines in jquery.countdown.js:

```
jQuery.fn.countdown = function(options) {
  return $.each(this, function(i, el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    if (!$el.data(NAME)) {
      // allow setting the date via the data-date attribute
      if ($el.data(DATA_ATTR)) {
        options.date = $el.data(DATA_ATTR);
      }
      $el.data(NAME, new Countdown(el, options));
    }
  });
};
```

to:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery.fn.countdown = function(options) {
      return $.each(this, function(i, el) {
        var $el = $(el);
        if (!$el.data(NAME)) {
          // allow setting the date via the data-date attribute
          if ($el.data(DATA_ATTR)) {
            options.date = $el.data(DATA_ATTR);
          }
          $el.data(NAME, new Countdown(el, options));
        }
      });
    };  
});
```

**Thank you all for your help !**